# ALTBEACON library - Background mode?

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

We are trying to build an app that continously does Beacon ranging and sends us data once per second.

The issue we found is, that the ALTBEACON library works fine and precise when display is ON. 
As soon as we switch display OFF the app stopps sending data in the pre-defined interval. In fact Android Studio logcat shows us it is not even recognizing the beacons, so it is not sending the data.

We do not have this issue with other beacon libraries, so we assume it is a programmatical issue.
Does anyone has a clue why this happens and how to prevent the app from stopping working with display OFF?

Manifest snippet

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="package_name" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
// other permissions 

-<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:allowBackup="false">

<activity android:name=".MyView" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFancyThemeWhiteNoActionBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
// other activity and services 

-<service android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService" tools:node="replace">

<meta-data android:name="longScanForcingEnabled" android:value="true"/>

</service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

JAVA snippet

```html
public class MyView extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
    Region region;

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for (Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    // doing my task.
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.landing_view);
        .
        .
        .
        .
        Identifier id1 = Identifier.parse(UUID);
        Identifier id2 = Identifier.parse(MAJOR);
        region = new Region("id", id1, id2, null);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);

        
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000L);
        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1000L);
        
        //new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
        BluetoothMedic medic = BluetoothMedic.getInstance();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            medic.enablePowerCycleOnFailures(this);
            medic.enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.SCAN_TEST | BluetoothMedic.TRANSMIT_TEST);
        }

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (beaconManager != null) {
            try {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                beaconManager.unbind(this);
            } catch (NullPointerException | RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I don't create any application class for background beacon detection. This task is going smoothly in foreground, I need it for background also. So if I need to change anything please comment.
I want to scan the beacons for every 1 sec interval in foreground as well as background also (when screen is going off). Background does not work ...

Comment: While there are many things that might cause this issue, it is important to note that I have not seen the same behavior with the library's [reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference), so it is worth testing that.  The most likely issue is in the code that sets up beacon detections, so please post a snippet of that code.  As well as a Logcat excerpt showing what happens when the screen goes off (system level logs may be helpful here.)  Also useful would be to know the device model and operating system version where this problem has been witnessed.

Comment: Have you declared the library's beaconservice and beacon broadcast receiver in the manifest file? Please let us know more about the issues that you are currently facing with the code snippet you tried with?

Comment: Please find the Logcat file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPRO49rg8q22Z1dLUN-q4Z9qJ14Trd3B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The log file appears to cover a two minute period from about 09:55:45 and 9:57:45. During this time, I it shows 483 beacon detections and 120 ranging callbacks. Example:   `Beacon packet detected for: id1: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 id2: 13 id3: 20002 with rssi -72`  Is this log file supposed to show a case with the screen off where beacons are not detected?

Comment: Please also comment on what Android device model you are using that experiences this issue.

Comment: We have issues with SAMSUNG XCover3, XCover 4 and Samsung S8+.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fTPOeKYChuVDH03iYEZNfyf_vt3UVDmVSyvHpMIKmpI
This is the new log file. We covered both states. ON -> OFF and OFF -> ON. 
The issue arises immediately after the display is off

Comment: That log excerpt is two minutes long from 9:55:46 to 9:57:46. There are regular detections throughout the log, the longest time between beacon detections is 4.9 seconds.  If this log file really does represent a time where your app stopped detecting beacons with the screen off, then it is not the library that is stopping detecting.  Perhaps there is something wrong with the `MyView` Activity class such that it is not able to receive the callbacks when the screen is off.  Are you sure it has not been destroyed?  You might try adding log lines to the lifecycle events of your Activity.